# Detect page unload with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a cancel button, that does an ajax and then refreshes page contents, and when navigating away I want to trigger the button, but I don't want it to refresh anything in the UI.

I thought of using a global variable, placed in the window object, but that does not seem very nice:

```
$(".cancel").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    tellTheServerThatUserCanceled(); // ajax call
    if (!isUnloading) refreshUI();
});

$(window).bind("unload", function(e) {
    isUnloading = true; // this is disgusting, I don't want to do this
    $(".cancel").trigger("click");
}
```

Is there any official way, or another more elegant way, or I shouldn't be worried about using global variables?

**EDIT:**
The `unload` event code does not know what exactly it must do, because the page can have multiple edit panels, with multiple cancel buttons. All it knows is that it must trigger the cancel buttons of each panel.

Answer (score 2):

I find its nicer not to run your code in jQuery's anonymous functions, but rather have them call functions that are sharable. Something like this illustrates the general idea:

```
function doCancel(e, isUnloading){
    e.preventDefault();
    tellTheServerThatUserCanceled(); // ajax call
    if (!isUnloading) refreshUI();
}

$(".cancel").bind("click", function(e) {
    doCancel(e, false);
});

$(window).bind("unload", function(e) {
    doCancel(e, true);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the unload event cannot be bound to a specific cancel function. The page is made of multiple panels, that when in edit-mode have cancel buttons... the unload event must cancel all panels in edit mode, calling each panel specific cancel function.